# Azure SQL Server database failed to connect from Power BI Dashboard

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database

I  am facing the Problem while connecting the Azure SQL Database from Power BI dashboard. I am getting the error as "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again". I am using the Alternate Credentials.

I have done the Firewall rules in Azure SQL Server as below :
Rule : for Everyone

Start IPv4 address : 0.0.0.0

End IPv4 Address  : 255.255.255.255

Its working fine with SQL Server Manager on same machine but fail from Power BI Dashbaord.

I have already googled it but no solution

[image]

Thanks

ST

Comment: Is "circa" a SQL authenticated login? Choose Database tab if so (not Windows) - and if it is AAD you will need "Microsoft Account"

Comment: Try with database authentication instead of windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks its working now by Database authentication instead of windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue in my environment I got the same error:

[image]

I changed authentication process from windows to database and entered the credentials.

[image]

It connected successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting MS power BI to Postgre SQL.

I'm facing the same problem. please try this, it will work.

To connect PostgreSQL to Power BI, you should use the appropriate username and password combination for the specific user you want to connect with. If you have not created any additional users, you can try using the default superuser "postgres" with the password you set during installation.